# How to convert JSON to a hash, search for and change a value

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to process a JSON file:

```
{
  "features": {
    "additional-options": true
  },
  "values": {
    "lo-value": 34,
    "hi-value": 554
  },
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "member": true,
      "current": false,
      "sponsor": "pete",
      "profile": "",
      "credits": ["04"],
      "linked": ["philip","guy"],
      "maptools": ["crossfit","soccer","running"]
    },
    {
      "name": "mary",
      "member": true,
      "current": false,
      "sponsor": "judy",
      "profile": "",
      "credits": ["all"],
      "activities": ["swimming","cycling","running"]
    }
  ],
  "data_map": [1122,3234]
}
```

I would like to be able to:

- Update a value on a key value pair
- Delete both the key/value
- Delete or insert a value that's an array

I have tried so many thing to get this right.

My simplified code idea is:

```
require 'json'

hash = JSON.parse(File.read('test.json'))

# Add key & value or change existing one
def change_key(hash, key, value)
    keys = key.strip(".")
    hash[*keys] = value
end

def add_to_array(hash, key, val)
    keys = key.strip(".")
    hash[*keys] = locate_arr(hash, key).insert(val)
end

# Delete a key and it's value
def del_key(hash, key)
    keys = key.strip(".")
    hash[*keys].delete[-1]
end

def del_from_array(hash, key, val)
    keys = key.strip(".")
    hash[*keys] = locate_arr(hash, key).delete[-1]
end

f = File.write('test.json') ; f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(hash)


change_key(hash, "features.additional-options", false)

del_from_array(hash, "persons.name=mary.activities", "cycling")

add_to_array(hash, "persons.name=mary.activities", "hockey")

del_key(hash, "data_map")

del_key(hash, persons.name=john.profile)

del_key(hash, persons.name=mary.credits)
```

The resulting JSON should be:

```
{
  "features": {
    "additional-options": false
  },
  "values": {
    "lo-value": 34,
    "hi-value": 554
  },
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "member": true,
      "current": false,
      "sponsor": "pete",
      "credits": ["04"],
      "linked": ["philip","guy"],
      "maptools": ["crossfit","soccer","running"]
    },
    {
      "name": "mary",
      "member": true,
      "current": false,
      "sponsor": "judy",
      "profile": "",
      "activities": ["swimming", "running","hockey"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure how to work with JSON that is structured like this.

Comment: the json you supplied from the file is invalid.

Comment: It should validate now.

Comment: I suggest you organize your data as an OpenStruct, then convert it to json again.

Comment: Looking around as to how. Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your JSON may look like this:

```
"{\"features\":{\"additional-options\":true},\"values\":{\"lo-value\":34,\"hi-value\":554},\"persons\":[{\"name\":\"john\",\"member\":true,\"current\":false,\"sponsor\":\"pete\",\"profile\":\"\",\"credits\":[\"04\"],\"linked\":[\"philip\",\"guy\"],\"maptools\":[\"crossfit\",\"soccer\",\"running\"]},{\"name\":\"mary\",\"member\":true,\"current\":false,\"sponsor\":\"judy\",\"profile\":\"\",\"credits\":[\"all\"],\"activities\":[\"swimming\",\"cycling\",\"running\"]}],\"data_map\":[1122,3234]}"
```

I suggest using an [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to organize your data:

```
your_struct_name =  JSON.parse(yourJson, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Then you get all the things you want. For the operations you show:

```
#change_key(hash, "features.additional-options", false)
your_struct_name.features['additional-options'] = false 
#this one above you set in this hash-like manner because of the '-' in the middle of the key. Otherwise you could just do your_struct_name.features.additional_options = false

#del_from_array(hash, "persons.name=mary.activities", "cycling")
your_struct_name.persons.last.activities.delete('swimming')

# or selecting by name:
your_struct_name.persons.select {|person| person.name == 'mary' }.first.activities.delete('swimming')

#add_to_array(hash, "persons.name=mary.activities", "hockey")
your_struct_name.persons.last.activities << 'hockey'

#del_key(hash, "data_map")
your_struct_name.delete_field('data_map')

#del_key(hash, persons.name=john.profile)
...

#del_key(hash, persons.name=mary.credits)
...
```

Then, after you make your changes, you can use:

```
your_struct_name.to_h.to_json
```

You can also use the method `as_json` to get a structure very similar to what you showed on the question:

```
your_struct_name.as_json
```

`OpenStruct` is very nice to deal with data that has a **changing structure**. If you have data that can be "modeled", has a name you can call, has some attributes you can predict, and even methods you will use for this data, I suggest you to create a Class to describe this data, its properties and attributes (it can even inherit from OpenStruct). Then work inside this Class domain, creating a layer of abstraction. This way your code gets a lot more robust and readable. Don't forget to create automatic tests! It saves you a lot of time.

The way you organize and abstract your data, and specially the way you name entities are things that have high impact on code quality.

For further reading see: [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html) and [ActiveData](https://github.com/pyromaniac/active_data).

Comment: This is interesting as I've never worked with Structs. How do I make it a JSON again?

Comment: I get this when using .to_json  `"\"#<OpenStruct features=#<OpenStruct additional-options=true>, values=#<OpenStruct lo-value=34, hi-value=554>, persons=[#<OpenStruct name=\\\"john\\\", member=true, current=false, sponsor=\\\"pete\\\", profile=\\\"\\\", credits=[\\\"04\\\"], linked=[\\\"philip\\\", \\\"guy\\\"], maptools=[\\\"crossfit\\\", \\\"soccer\\\", \\\"running\\\"]>, #<OpenStruct name=\\\"mary\\\", member=true, current=false, sponsor=\\\"swift-water\\\", profile=\\\"\\\", credits=[\\\"all\\\"], activities=[\\\"cycling\\\", \\\"running\\\"]>], data_map=[1122, 3234]>\""`

Comment: @ditty_one Sorry. I corrected that. You must convert to hash before converting to json again. The openstruct implements the to_h (to hash conversion)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried converting to hash first and then to json but  the `#<OpenStruct ` is still there and converts the keys to symbols `: features`